# Laravel get most popular product

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

Im having 2 tables one with products and one favourit to keep it simple i show the relevant rows.

**table poducts**

id

---

**table favourit**

user_id *not needed in query*

product_id

---

What i want is find the top 10 of products wich are most common in the favourit table. I think i have to do

```
   favourit::groupBy(product_id)
```

and

```
   favourit::orderBy(ammount(sum of all product_ids), desc)
```

But how can i get the ammount(sum of all product_ids) to order by? Also would this query (with a groupby) be possible to be joined with the products table so i get the products in one query?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to write the query like this:
This is an adaptation from Caveman42 Sql query.

```
favourit::select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as count'))
->groupBy('product_id')
->orderBy('count', 'desc')
->take(10);
```

Then, i'm not sure how to get the relation with your products.

Edit: If your relation is set in your product model. You should be able to join the product table using the with() function:

```
favourit::with('product')
->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as count'))
->groupBy('product_id')
->orderBy('count', 'desc')
->take(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

From an `SQL` point of view, this is how you would get the top 10 products from the favorit table:

```
Select TOP 10
    Product_id
    ,COUNT(Product_id) as [Count]
From
    favorit
Group By
    Product_id
Order By
    COUNT(Product_id) desc
```

This will give you the top 10 Product_id's and sort them with the highest count on top.

I am not too familiar with `PHP` so I wouldn't be able to tell you how to implement it, sorry :(